# Записать в функцию правильно значения 0 та 1

Tags: c#

Функцияя принимает на вход массив, содержащий 0 и 1 в произвольном порядке

И должна  вернуть массив, так чтобы сначала шли 0 а потом уже 1. Но она выводит только 0. Где я  натупила?

```
    static int[] IntArray(int[] array)
    {
        int indexNew = 0;
        int[] arrayNew = new int[array.Length];
        for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; ++index)
        {
            if (array[index] == 0)
                 ++indexNew;
        }
        for (int index = 0; index < indexNew; ++index)
        {
                arrayNew[index] = 0;
        }

        for (int index = indexNew; index < array.Length; ++index)
        {
                arrayNew[index] = 1;
        }
        return arrayNew;
    }
```

Comment: Да почти в каждой строчке. Второй цикл ни разу не выполняется, в первом вы делаете не то, что написано в задаче. С карандашом и листком бумаги пройдитесь по своему алгоритму.

Comment: `сначала шли 0 а потом уже 1` пробовали сортировать массив?

Comment: @tym32167 в условии задания:  нельзя  использовать вбудованые функции для сортировки, а как в  ручну я  что то не могу  придумать , по  другому. Только как написала в коде

Comment: Только что созданный массив и так заполнен нулями, вам не надо в нем нули проставлять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто посчитаем единицы и заполним выходной массив ими с конца

```
static int[] IntArray(int[] array)
{
    var count = array.Length;
    var ones = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<count; i++)
    if (array[i] == 1) ones++;

    var ret = new int[array.Length];
    for(int i=count-1; i>count-1-ones; i--)     
        ret[i] = 1;

    return ret;
}
```

Ну, или более понятный вариант, посчитать нули и проставить единицы  с позиции после последнего ноля.

```
static int[] IntArray(int[] array)
{
    var count = array.Length;
    var zeroes = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<count; i++)
    if (array[i] == 0) zeroes++;

    var ret = new int[array.Length];
    for(int i=zeroes; i<count; i++) 
        ret[i] = 1;

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто посчитайте во входящем массиве количество нулей (и единиц). И назначьте в начале выходного массива соответствующее количество нулей, а остальным элементам до конца массива - присвойте единицы.

---

Два последних можно `for` в Вашем решении заменить на один.

```
    for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; ++index)
    {
            arrayNew[index] = (index < indexNew)? 0 : 1;
    }
```

---

А давайте, вообще одним циклом сделаем.

```
int indexNew = array.Length - 1;
int[] arrayNew = new int[array.Length];
for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; ++index)
{
  if (array[index] == 1)
    arrayNew[indexNew--] = 1;
}
```

Comment: эх, чуть чуть меня опередили :)

Comment: @Igor переделала, работате. Посмотрите я изменю свой вопрос и віложу туда код,  мне не  нравится что у меня 3 фора

Answer (score 0):

второй цикл for:

int index = arrayNew.Length; index < array.Length; ++index

индекс = длине массива, и Вы его увеличиваете

++index

что сразу же выходит за рамки условия

index < array.Length

пройдитесь по циклу точно также как и в первом for

и для нового цикла индекс должен быть свой независимый в обоих for

Comment: @users323281 но если я  так  сделаю то я  запишу массив которій у меня  есть. а мне нужно сначала  0 потом 1

Comment: да Вы правы, я дополнил свой ответ

Answer (score 0):

не удержался

```
static int[] IntArray(int[] array)
    {
    int indexNew =0;
        int[] arrayNew = new int[array.Length];
        for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; ++index)
        {
            if (array[index] == 0)
                arrayNew[indexNew] = 0;
    ++indexNew;
        }
        for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; ++index)
        {
            if (array[index] == 1)
                arrayNew[indexNew] = 1;
    ++indexNew;
        }
        return arrayNew;
    }
```

попробуйте сам не проверял

Comment: ошибка - Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.